# Excel countif four criteria are met with a range issue

Tags: excel, range, formula, countif

I am trying to count only times when column E matches a range on another sheet **and** column AA matches a different range on another sheet.  I can count the times column E matches a cell in the first range with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Class Failure Report'!$E:$E,Classes!B1:N1))
```

But I can't count the times column AA matches the other range **if** the first condition is met.

My best guess so far is something like:

```
COUNTIF('All Class Failure Report'!$E:$E,(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Class Failure Report'!$E:$E,Classes!B1:N1)) and (SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Class Failure Report'!$AA:$AA,Classes!B34:N34)))))
```

However this returns an error.

Question: can I get the count of times Row E contains value from a range and Row AA contains a value from a different range?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using COUNTIFS (which allows mulitple criteria)?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('All Class Failure Report'!$E:$E,Classes!B1:N1,'All Class Failure Report'!$AA:$AA,Classes!B34:N34))
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks so much!